# Making string into list in python

Tags: python, string, list

For my program I have a function that changes a string into a list however when it hits a newline character it combines the two words on either side of the newline character. Example:

```
"newline\n   problem"
```

Prints out like this in main function:

```
print(serperate_words)
newlineproblem
```

Here is the code:

```
def stringtolist(lines):
    # string of acceptable characters
    acceptable = "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'’- " 
    new_string = ''
    for i in lines:
        # runs through the string and checks to see what characters are in the string
        if i in acceptable:
            i = i.lower()
            # if it is an acceptable character it is added to new string
            new_string += i
        elif i == '.""':
            # if it is a period or quotation marks it is replaced with a space in the new string
            new_string += ' '
        else:
            # for every other character it is removed and not added to new string
            new_string += ''


    #splits the string into a list
    seperate_words = new_string.split(' ')
    return seperate_words
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the seperator?

Comment: Just FYI:  `for i in lines: if i in acceptable: i = i.lower()` will not modify your string. This is because in Python, every name is a reference, so if you assign a reference to something else, the originally referenced object will not change. Methods are the most common way of mutating mutable objects (which btw, strings are not mutable in python).

Comment: Why don't you use the split method?

Comment: use     `line_break="\n"
    lines = lines.replace(line_break,"")`

Comment: @MTaqi Thanks that worked to replace the newlines right at the beginning for a space so that the program wouldn't connect the two words.

Answer (score 1):

You can split a string with multiple delimiters:

```
def stringtolist(the_string):
    import re
    return re.split('[ \.\n]', the_string)
```

You can add other delimiters to the list if you want (like quotes, ...) => `re.split('[ \.\n\'\"]', the_string)`

Answer (score 0):

You can just check for the newline character and skip it. Here's an example.

```
for word in string:
    if ch is not '/n':
        newstring += ch
```

Or use

```
.strip() to remove newlines altogether
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the multiple transformations described in the comments of the original code, a more flexible approach could be to use the [`translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method of strings (together with the [`maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) function):

```
def stringtolist(lines):
    import string
    acceptable_chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + "'`- "
    space_chars = '."'
    delete_chars = ''.join(set(map(chr, xrange(256))) - set(acceptable_chars))
    table = string.maketrans(acceptable + space_chars, acceptable.lower() + (' '*len(space_chars)))
    return lines.translate(table, delete_chars).split()
```